# Probability Question: Continuous Probability

Tags: probability

I'm trying to **identify** and answer the question below, so far I think it's to do with **continuous random variables**, and the **normal distribution*, though not sure if this is correct, and how to go from there.

.....An airline's load calculations use the assumptions that the weight of a passenger's hand luggage is **6 kg on average**, with a **standard deviation of 3 kg**, and that the weights of different passengers' hand luggage are **independent**. Based on these assumptions,

*calculate approximately the probability that the combined weight of the hand luggage of 150 passengers exceeds 1000 kg.*

Thanks!

Comment: The variables must not to be continuous. You can apply the *central limit theorem* to approximate the distribution of the summed weight of the hand luggages.

Comment: Ok, so using the theorem, I'm trying to figure out the z-score.
mew = 6,
sigma = 3,
n = 150,
but what would xbar = ? 

How would I get this value? Thanks! :D

Comment: I'm thinking xbar might be 1000/150?

Comment: $\overline x$ is not needed here since it is asked for the weight of all luggages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the random variable of the  weight for the passenger i luggage.

And $ Y$ is the random variable of the total weight of the luggages.

Then $Y=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{150} X_i$

Now we can apply the central limit theorem. The sum of i.i.d variables is $\texttt{approximately}$ normally distributed if $n$ is sufficient large enough. One rule of thumb is $ n>30$.

$\mathbb E(Y)=150\cdot \mathbb E(X_i)=150\cdot 6$

$Var(Y)= 150\cdot Var( X_i)=150\cdot 3^2\Rightarrow \sigma_y=3\cdot \sqrt{150}$

$P(Y>1000)=1-P(Y\leq 1000)\approx 1-\Phi\left( \frac{y-\mu_y}{\sigma_y}\right)=1-\Phi\left( \frac{1000-900}{3\cdot \sqrt{150}}\right)$

$\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution. I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Wow nice O_o! Thanks!

Comment: Nice that it helps. If you have any further questions feel free to ask. Your are welcome.

Comment: Note that the variance of $Y$ is $150$ times the variance of $X_i$, not $150^2$ times.

Comment: @copper.hat Ouch. Thanks for your helpful comment.

Comment: @callculus: Glad to help. My personal mnemonic is to just assume the $X_i$ are actually normal, then the computation is straightforward.